# Vector iterator not dereferencable (vector inside vector)

Tags: c++, vector, struct, dereference, ofstream

I am trying to write some data from these vectors onto text files. When I run the code it returns a run time error. `Category`, `Product`, `Cart`, `Customer`and `Address` are all `struct` with members that each `get_member` returns.

```
ofstream write_cats;
    write_cats.open("catprd.dat", ios::out, ios::trunc);
    vector<Category>::iterator i;
    write_cats << cats.size() << endl;
    for (i = cats.begin(); i < cats.end(); i++) {
        write_cats << i -> get_catid() << '\t';
        }
    vector<Product>::iterator j;
    write_cats << prods.size() << endl;
    for (j = prods.begin(); j < prods.end(); j++) {
        write_cats << j -> get_prodid() << '\t';
        write_cats << j -> get_prodprice() << endl;
        }
    write_cats.close();

    ofstream write_carts;
    write_carts.open("carts.dat", ios::out, ios::trunc);
    vector<Cart>::iterator k;
    write_carts << carts.size() << endl;
    for (k = carts.begin(); k < carts.end(); k++) {
        write_carts << k -> get_cartid() << '\t';
        write_carts << k -> get_day() << endl;
        }
    vector<Cart_item>::iterator l;
    write_carts << cart_items.size() << endl;
    for (l = cart_items.begin(); l < cart_items.end(); l++) {
        write_carts << l -> get_cartitemid() << '\t';
        write_carts << l -> get_qty() << endl;
        }
    write_carts.close();

    ofstream write_custs;
    write_custs.open("custs.dat", ios::out, ios::trunc);
    vector<Customer>::iterator m;
    vector<Address>::iterator n;
    write_custs << custs.size() << endl;
    for (m = custs.begin(); m < custs.end(); m++) {
        write_custs << m -> get_cust_id() << '\t';
        write_custs << n -> get_zip_code() << endl;
        }
    write_custs.close();
```

Returns run time error "Vector iterator not dereferencable"

Here is how `struct Address` looks like:

```
using namespace std;
#pragma once
#include <string>

struct Address {

public:

int get_st_number() const{return st_number;} 
int get_zip_code() const{return zip_code;} 
string get_st_name() const{return st_name;} 



Address(){}                                 
Address (int num, string name, int zip) 
    : st_number(num), st_name(name), zip_code(zip) {}

private:
int st_number;
int zip_code;
string st_name;


};
```

and `struct Customer`:

```
struct Customer {
public:

Address get_address() const{return addr;} 
int get_cust_id() const{return cust_id;}  customer id
string get_name() const{return cust_name;} 
Customer (int id, string n, Address a)  
    : cust_id(id), cust_name(n), addr(a) {}


string display_addr() const {
    std::cout<<setw(15)<<cust_name<<" ";
    std::cout<<setw(15)<<cust_id<<" ";

    return string();
}



private:

int cust_id;
string cust_name;
Address addr;           
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code fragment is both too long and too short. It is too long, and filled with too much extraneous goo for people to understand. It is also too short; it is missing the key pieces required to compile. Please create a **short**, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem you are having. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forget to initialize `vector<Address>::iterator n;`

Comment: It's right under vector<Customer>::iterator m; Unless you mean within the for loop for iterator m? How would the code look like?

Comment: @user1314967: You declare it, but never give it a valid (dereferencable) value, like you do to `m` with `m = custs.begin()`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour If I use `m` for both `struct Customer` and `struct Address` then it tells me that the members of `Address` are not part of `Customer`. I try to reach to `Address` in `Customer` through `Address get_address() const{return addr;}` but I can't call for a member in `Address` for example `st_number` which is an `int` in `Address` with a function of `int get_stnum() { return st_number; }`

Comment: @user1314967: Why doesn't `m->get_address().get_stnum()` work? What is the error?

Comment: maybe you need to search in your addresses' vector for the customer address?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I provided `Address` and `Customer` so you can see how they are together. I removed most of the elements that are being called in each vector iterator because of what @Rob said. But you should get the idea, I am trying to write all the data that the vectors store back into each text file being opened. When I run that segment of code it returns a run time error stating `Vector iterator not dereferencable` along with other general details.

Comment: n seems useless: `write_custs << m -> get_address().get_zip_code() << endl;` should do

Comment: @chac: I see now, and @MikeSeymour sorry I missed what you said there. It seems to be working by using `m->get_address().get_stnum()` I was overlooking my `get_address()` function as I created it for another use but never really used it when I needed it, instead went with `Address addr:`.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an iterator `n`, but not initialising it to a dereferencable value. From your update, it looks like you want to print the `Address` associated with the customer; so you'd access via the customer referred to by `m`, rather than a separate iterator:

```
write_custs << m -> get_cust_id() << '\t';
write_custs << m -> get_address().get_zip_code() << endl;
```

Also, it might be a good idea to scope each iterator inside its loop; that's less error-prone than declaring a new one in the outer scope each time:

```
for (vector<Whatever>::const_iterator i = stuff.begin(); i != stuff.end(); ++i) {
    // do stuff with "i"
}
// "i" is no longer available - no danger of accidentally using it again.
```

And a couple of other points:

- You should use `!=` rather than `<` to compare with the `end()` iterator; `<` doesn't work for some types of iterator;
- You should write a new-line to the file as `'\n'` rather than `endl`; `endl` flushes the file buffer, forcing the file to be written to disk at that point, which can be extremely slow.

Comment: Awesome, I will make those changes. I've been learning C++ for a couple of months or so.